# Pixelation Issue with Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, pixel

I have been using Unity to make a running game and there has been some issues with pixelation during the run game process. I found online that if you increases the max size to 2048 on the Import Settings that should improve the quality but whenever I do that my parallax script doesn't work the way it should be. For example the image will scroll by once and not repeat itself. I have been using planes with materials placed on top of them to fix transparency issues I had before. I am not sure if there is anything wrong with the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ParallaxBackground : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Speed= 0.4f;

    void Update() {
        float offset = Time.time * Speed;
        renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(offset, 0);
    }
}
```

I know if I just place sprites up without the planes supporting them that I can improve the pixelation and still use the parallax script but at the cost of transarency issues(you can see slight distortions in the images) like a semi-cloak part of the image which should be transparent. I am not sure how to fix this problem and would gladly accept your help.

Answer (score -1):

It may have something to do with publish settings, in publishing the settings of the Apps H x W pixels display should be in even numbers, not odd or fractional values ie 480x640 or the resolution & text can be pixelated in Unity 3d.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the script posted. This could be a comment, but it doesn't attempt to answer the question at hand.